# pass two instance variables to js.erb files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to pass two instance variables to a javascript file that is being used by an ajax request to update a user display. This is what I need to do:

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
        format.js { @post @user_vote }  # <-- right here
    else 
        format.html { redirect_to :back, :alert => 'There was an error in removing the vote' }
    end
end
```

How is this done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no need to pass the instance variables if you use js.erb files. You can directly put the rails tag and access those variables inside the js.erb file

Eg:

In your controller just put

```
format.js #instead of format.js { @post @user_vote }
```

and in js.erb file you can access the instance variable as

```
$('#ele').html("<%= @post.name %>");
```

Answer (score 2):

The instance variables in your ActionController action are available in your views automagically. E.g. your controller:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def update

  # Your implementation here
  @post = ...
  @user_vote = ...

  respond_to do |format|
    if @post.save
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
    else
      format.js { ... }
      format.html { redirect_to :back, ... }
    end
  end
end
```

Then in your update.js.erb:

```
# update.js.erb
console.log('Post: <%= @post.inspect %>');
console.log('User vote: <%= @user_vote %>');

# Your JS implementation here
```

(Also I noticed your logic in the respond_to block is probably going to cause problems. You should render both js and html formats for both success and failure conditions of `@post.save`.)